# Why network isn't working after changes of proxychains4

Tags: firefox, proxychains

```
sudo nano /etc/proxychains4.conf
```

`Dynamic chain` is open. Then, I `#/comment` others(strict chain,random chain,round robin chain) Another changes I made `socks4 125.26.99.2 44052`. Then, I run proxychains on firefox

```
proxychains firefox google.com
```

[image]

[image]

After few minutes : [image]

They are loading loading and loading.................
I don't know why this is happening. Those websites aren't opening...

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

My proxychains filename is proxychains4 that's why I thought it would work if I run the following command

```
proxychains4 firefox google.com
```

Nonetheless, I am getting same error [image]

Comment: You have to clarify: 1/ give the complete configuration 2/ 2.1/ was it working before the change? give the former working configuration. or 2.2/ Was it not working either? Change the title

Comment: @A.B Yes! Network is working when I run firefox by that command `proxychains firefox google.com` Network wasn't working... after changes in proxychains also...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working after using `Tor` service.

```
sudo apt-get install tor

sudo service tor start

proxychains4 firefox google.com
```

[image]