# how to enable proxychains globally?

Tags: kali-linux, ip, proxychains

I was running proxychains [this way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/640536/449077). I am getting different ip addresses each time. But, now the problem is when I run any application without that command (`proxychains4 firefox`) than I get my real ip address. So, I want to set dynamic ip globally. If I run proxychains than ip addresses should be change everywhere. In this [link](https://linuxhint.com/proxychains-tutorial/) they run nmap this way(`proxychains nmap 192.168.1.1/24` ) But, I want to run nmap(any application) without proxychains that's why I have to run proxychains globally but, how?

Comment: I would recommend to use different user for your "hacking" and use iptables with `--uid-owner <username>` and redirect to Tor (if this is what you want to do).

Comment: Please don't post URL links where people should read about your setup, not everybody would follow the link... Just write it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`openvpn` is better than proxychains.

```
sudo apt-get install openvpn
```

[`openvpn` server](https://www.vpnbook.com/).

```
sudo openvpn --config vpnbook-us1-tcp443.ovpn
```

> username : vpnbook
>
> password : 4dK5esN

Then click on return. vpn will be start shortly. Then, you can access anything from another ip addresses

Answer (score 0):

Before using proxychains, you require to set up a proxychains configuration file. You also require a list of the proxy server. proxychains configuration file located on /etc/proxychains.conf

Open proxychains.conf file in your desirable text editor and set up some configuration. Scroll down until you end at the bottom, at the end of the file you will find [proxylist]

Now, we require to join more proxies. There are free proxy servers on the Internet, you may search at Google for it. Comment the default proxy for Tor if you are not applying Tor then join the proxy on the Proxychains config file, then save it.