# using of sqlmap by different ip addresses

Tags: kali-linux, ip, sql, proxychains

```
sqlmap -u http://192.168.0.106/get_method/get_data/?id=1 --dbs
```

I know that if we sent any request to any server that server takes ip address of user(mine). So, while I am running the above source code server is getting my ip address. So, they can easily find me. ~ I am not sure of the information also.

In Kali-Linux, there's something called `proxychains.conf`. I was trying to use that

```
proxychains4 sqlmap -u http://192.168.0.106/get_method/get_data/?id=1 --dbs
```

But, proxychains not working [image] I am saying that by `[proxychains] Dynamic chain  ...  127.0.0.1:9050  ...  192.168.0.106:80 <--denied`. I am getting data by above code also but, not using different ip addresses ~I think I am not sure of it also. So, I want to change my ip address every moment when I works with sqlmap or any other vulnerability.

I am totally Newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same answer as [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/641156/449077)

`openvpn` is better than proxychains.

```
sudo apt-get install openvpn
```

[`openvpn` server](https://www.vpnbook.com/).

```
sudo openvpn --config vpnbook-us1-tcp443.ovpn
```

> username : vpnbook
>
> password : 4dK5esN

**Password always changes so keep connect with the website https://vpnbook.com**

Then click on return. vpn will be start shortly. Then, you can access anything from another ip addresses